# Заполнение таблицы 2, используя обновляемые данные таблицы 1

Tags: excel, vba

Есть две таблицы в эксель.

Таблица 1.

```
Дата    01.01.2021
Статья 1    30
Статья 2    40
Статья 3    50
```

Таблица 2.

```
Дата       Статья 1   Статья 2  Статья 3
01.01.2021   30          40       50
02.01.2021          
03.01.2021
```

Я хочу, чтобы таблица номер 2 стала моей базой данных, а таблица номер 1 превратилась в вводное поле.

Другими словами, я хочу иметь возможность вводить данные в таблицу номер 1 таким образом, чтобы они автоматически отображались в таблице номер 2 с привязкой к дате, которая указана в таблице номер 1.

Алгоритм:

1. Указываю дату в таблице 1, указываю значения для полей "Статья 1, 2, 3";
2. Данные переходят в таблицу номер 2 с привязкой по дате и статьям;
3. Указываю новую дату и изменяю данные для полей "Статья 1, 2, 3" в таблице номер 1 ;
4. Данные переходят в таблицу номер 2 с привязкой к новой дате;
5. При этом данные, которые были указаны на шаге алгоритма 1, сохраняются в таблице два, далее меняются только при явном указании через таблицу номер 1.

Понимаю, что это как то можно сделать с помощью макросов, но не знаю как

Comment: На основании таблицы 1 строите сводную таблицу 2. Организуете автоматический пересчёт сводной таблицы по изменению исходных данных. Вот только даты в строках - будут исключительно те, что присутствуют в исходных данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прицепить на листе, где водятся данные, какой-либо объект (кнопку, например), назначить ему макрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем модуле разместить код:

```
Sub SaveData()
    Dim aData(), aBase()
    Dim lRw As Long
    
    aData = Worksheets("Лист1").Range("B1:B4").Value
    
    With Worksheets("Лист2")
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        aBase = .Range("A1:D" & lRw).Value
        
        lRw = fFindDate(aBase, aData(1, 1))
        .Cells(lRw, 1).Value = aData(1, 1): .Cells(lRw, 2).Value = aData(2, 1)
        .Cells(lRw, 3).Value = aData(3, 1): .Cells(lRw, 4).Value = aData(4, 1)
    End With
    
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub

' поиск даты '
Function fFindDate(aBase(), ByVal dDate As Date) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To UBound(aBase)
        If aBase(i, 1) = dDate Then
            fFindDate = i: Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    fFindDate = UBound(aBase) + 1
End Function
```

В зависимости от даты на первом листе данные на втором листе или записываются в  строку под последней записью, или (если дата найдена) перезаписываются в строке с этой датой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]