# Перевод макроса VBA в JavaScript для использования его в таблицах гугл

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

Необходимо провести адаптацию кода, решающего проблему, описанную в запросе: [Заполнение таблицы 2, используя обновляемые данные таблицы 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226235/).

У меня на руках есть макрос VBA для эксель:

```
Sub SaveData()
    Dim aData(), aBase()
    Dim lRw As Long
    
    aData = Worksheets("Лист1").Range("B1:B4").Value
    
    With Worksheets("Лист2")
        lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Row - 1
        aBase = .Range("A1:D" & lRw).Value
        
        lRw = fFindDate(aBase, aData(1, 1))
        .Cells(lRw, 1).Value = aData(1, 1): .Cells(lRw, 2).Value = aData(2, 1)
        .Cells(lRw, 3).Value = aData(3, 1): .Cells(lRw, 4).Value = aData(4, 1)
    End With
    
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub

' поиск даты '
Function fFindDate(aBase(), ByVal dDate As Date) As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To UBound(aBase)
        If aBase(i, 1) = dDate Then
            fFindDate = i: Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    fFindDate = UBound(aBase) + 1
End Function
```

Необходимо модернизировать его таким образом, чтобы он запускался в таблицах гугл докс.

Comment: ну дерзайте. Тут немного другой формат общения. Вам необходимо вы делаете. А мы можем помочь если что будет конкретный вопрос

Comment: @AzizUmarov, да я бы дерзал, если бы хоть что то понимал в VBA или js. Вдохновился постом https://habr.com/ru/post/535770. Решил сделать табличку эксель для логирования активностей в течение дня. Для удобства использования оказалось, что нужно написать макрос, мне его любезно написали. Теперь оказалось, что для совместимости с гугл доксами необходимо его модернизировать. Можно, конечно, и без макросов все руками забивать в общую табличку, собственно, так я сейчас и поступаю, но все же, мне кажется, задача интересная, вдруг найдется человек, которому она придется по душе.